# Restore a dependent type at runtime

Tags: scala, dependent-type, path-dependent-type

I'm trying to restore a dependent type in Scala at runtime. I basically want to archive a type-save map, where every key has an associated type, but all type informations of the stored key value pairs aren't visible to the user of Map (unlike the awesome [Shapeless Map](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps)).

```
class Key[V] {
  type Value = V
  def ->(value: V) = Pair(this, value)
}
trait Pair {
  val key: Key[_]
  val value: key.Value
}
trait Map {
  val pairs: Seq[Pair]
  def get[V](key: Key[V]): Option[V] =
    pairs.find(pair => pair.key eq key).map(_.value).asInstanceOf[Option[V]]
    //                          ^                              ^
    //   the runtime prove that pair.key.Value equals V        |
    //                                                         |
    //                        'Convince' the compile that I know what I do
}
```

Usage:

```
val text = new Key[String]
val count = new Key[Int]
val map: Map = new Map { val pairs = text -> "Hello World!" :: Nil }

map.get(text)  // Some(Hello World!), Type: Option[String]
map.get(count) // None, Type: Option[Int]
```

Is it possible to write a `get` method without using a cast explicit with `asInstanceOf` or implicit with a match with an unchecked branch?

I tried to write an `unapply` for pairs, but run into the same problem.

Note that I leave out the definition of the Pair-companion object. Here a running example in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Jentsch/d77193839ba83e07e8f5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the JVM erases generics at runtime. So anything that relies on generics, including dependent typing, can only happen at compile time - i.e. in the caller, because any given method will only compile to one runtime code path. The only alternative is checking the runtime class (either directly or by pattern matching) as you say. (Shapeless has a type-safe, typeclass-driven helper if you go down that route)

There might be a clever way to express your requirements without the type issues, but in general the type information has to be either visible to the caller or checked at runtime.

Comment: Since there only concrete instances, I don't think the runtime erasure is a problem here. Or the other way around, I don't see where generic type informations could help in this situation. There have to be a runtime check, but may the compiler could be convinced that a second one isn't necessary.

Comment: The `get` method is generic, so it can't have different codepaths for different `Value`s. So either the calling code must have visibility on the `Key`/`Value` relationship, or it's a runtime check.

Answer (score 0):

Many way to solve your type issue. First of all define source of issue:

```
trait Map {
  val pairs: Seq[Pair]                     // (1)
  def get[V](key: Key[V]): Option[V] =     // (2)
    pairs.find(_.key eq key).map{_.value } // (3)
}
```

1. `pairs` type is `Seq` of `Pair` (with some embedded undefined type `key: Key[_]`)
2. `key` type is `Key[V]` and expected result type is `Option[V]`
3. try to return type from (1) `Key[_]` instead of expected `Key[V]` and extracted V

Solution: you should guaranty that `pairs` embedded type of `key` is the same what you return

One of possible solutions:

```
trait Key[V] {
  def ->(value: V) = Pair(this, value)
}

trait Pair {
  type Value
  val key: Key[Value]
  val value: Value
}

trait Map1[V] {
  val pairs: Seq[Pair {type Value = V } ]

  def get(key: Key[V]): Option[V] =
    pairs.find(_.key eq key).map{ _.value }
}

trait Map2 {
  type Value

  val pairs: Seq[Pair {type Value = Map2.this.Value} ]

  def get[V >: Map2.this.Value](key: Key[V]): Option[V] =
    pairs.find(_.key eq key).map{ _.value }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my question was ambiguous. I meant a map could have multiple keys with different `Value` types. I extended the question by an usage example.

How ever, I like to thank you for your answer.